# Problem in combining hyperref with multibib

Tags: hyperref, natbib, multibib

I am writing my thesis and the document (in `book` class) contains multiple lists of references, one per chapter. Thus, I am using `multibib` package and the command `\newcites` to group the citations in the correct lists. I am combining that with `natbib`, since I want the `apa` style. Further, I am using `hyperref` package to generate the hyperlinks all over the document.

I have references that are repeated in different reference lists, since they are cited in different chapters.

My problem is that hyperref always point such citations to the first reference list where it appears. For instance, if a specific citation appears twice in chapter I and chapter II, the hyperref will point the citation in chapter II to the reference list of chapter I and not to the list of chapter II.

Here you have the relevant code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliotest.bib}

 @article{author2014,
   author       = "Author",
   title        = "Title of the paper",
   journal      = "The Journal",
   volume       = "1",
   number       = "1",
   pages        = "1-2",
   month        = "September",
   year         = "2014",
 }
 \end{filecontents*} 


 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english,pdftex]{book}
 \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{babel}
 \usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx} 
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 %citation Harvard style
 \usepackage{natbib}
 \bibpunct{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}

 %Multiple reference sections (per chapter)
 \usepackage{multibib}
 \def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt}
 \newcites{oneintro}{References 1}
 \newcites{twomatproc}{References 2}

 \begin{document}

   \chapter{Intro}

    I am citing for the first time this reference here. \citeponeintro{author2014}

   %%%%%%%%The Biliography%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   \renewcommand{\bibname}{References 1}
   \bibliographystyleoneintro{apa}
   \bibliographyoneintro{bibliotest}


   \chapter{Methods}

     And now, I am citing it once again in this chapter. \citeptwomatproc{author2014}

   %%%%%%%%%The bibliography%%%%%%%%%%%%  
   \renewcommand{\bibname}{References 2}
   \bibliographystyletwomatproc{apa}
   \bibliographytwomatproc{bibliotest}

   \end{document}
```

The `.bib` file is included in the MWE with package `filelists`.

I have tried to debug this problem looking for answers on the internet but without success. Could you help me?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please revise your question and use some paragraphs to facilitate its readability.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use `biblatex` instead.  It has a `refsection` feature for bibliographies per section, and it works with `hyperref` correctly.  You just have to use `biber` instead of `bibtex`.  A `biblatex` version of your sample document with the `apa` style would be:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliotest.bib}

@article{author2014,
  author       = "Author",
  title        = "Title of the paper",
  journal      = "The Journal",
  volume       = "1",
  number       = "1",
  pages        = "1-2",
  month        = "September",
  year         = "2014",
}
\end{filecontents*} 


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,american,pdftex]{book}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color,graphicx} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\addbibresource{bibliotest.bib}

\begin{document}


\chapter{Intro}

I am citing for the first time this reference
here. \parencite{author2014}

\printbibliography

\chapter{Methods}

And now, I am citing it once again in this
chapter. \parencite{author2014}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for your answers.

I managed to solve my problem reading the inchapter 1.3 Limitations, as suggested. In the .bib file, I introduced two entries with different labels for the same reference and then I used each label in the citations corresponding to the reference list of the specific chapter. For instance, according to the previous example, the citation becomes `\citeponeintro{author2014I}` for chapter 1 and it becomes `\citeptwomatproc{author2014II}` for chapter 2.

Nevertheless, I might use biblatex in the future, since the the solution proposed here in this thread looks much simpler. Ana