# How get hyperref links to 2nd bibliography with multibib and amsplain bibtex style?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, multibib, amsplain

Is it possible to get `hyperref` hyperlinks on a 2nd bibliography with the `multibib` package **and the `amsplain` BibTeX style**?

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{two}{More Information}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Rome J. Gastronomical Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Popular Math.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{second.bib}
@book{BourbakiSets1970,Author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},Title={Th{\'e}orie des ensembles},
Year={1970},Publisher={Hermann},Location={Paris}}
\end{filecontents}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$, respectively.

Bourbaki~\citetwo{BourbakiSets1970} treats set theory axiomatically.

\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\bibliography{main}
\bibliographystyletwo{amsplain}
\bibliographytwo{second}

\end{document}
```

[image: Missing hyperlink to 2nd bibliography]

Other posts propose solving this either by using `natbib` (e.g., [multibib - hyperref doesn't work for my second bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105718/multibib-hyperref-doesnt-work-for-my-second-bibliography)) or `biblatex` (e.g., [Problem in combining hyperref with multibib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199721/problem-in-combining-hyperref-with-multibib)).

However, I am wedded to the `amsplain` bibtex style, which does not seem to be available with either `natbib` or `biblatex`.

Is there some workaround? Even hacks to `hyperref` or `multibib` would be OK (although, of course, not preferable).

**Partial solution**

Following the helpful suggestions by @jon, the following modified source does use `biblatex` to create two bibliographies, with hyperlinks to each from `hyperref`. The two bibliographies are independent, as I want; and no mods are needed in the source `.bib` files. I have not yet tackled the issue of modifying the bib style so as to resemble `amsplain`.

However, the 2nd printed bibliography resets the counter at 1, despite my attempt to manually reset it.

**Is there a way to continue numbering in the 2nd bibliography after where the numbering in the 1st bibliography ends?**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{two.bib}
@book{BourbakiSets1970,Author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},Title={Th{\'e}orie des ensembles},
Year={1970},Publisher={Hermann},place={Paris}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{main.bib}
\addbibresource{two.bib}

\begin{document}

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$,  respectively.

\printbibliography % main

\newrefsection
\defbibnote{readprenote}{Here are some suggested readings.}
\printbibliography[title={Additional Readings},resetnumbers=3,prenote=readprenote] % two 

Bourbaki~\cite{BourbakiSets1970} treats set theory axiomatically.

\end{document}
```

[image: Misnumbered 2nd bibliography]

**Fix for 2nd bibliography numbering**

Using the `refsegment` environment from `biblatex`, instead of `\newrefsection`, and adding the `defernumbers=true` option when loading `biblatex`, seems to fix the numbering problem: by default, numbering of the 2nd bibliography resumes with the next number after the last number in the 1st bibliography.

Here's the complete source again but with that modification:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}    
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hyperindex,colorlinks, citecolor=red} 

\begin{filecontents}{main.bib}
@article{Archimedes200,author = {Archimedes},title = {Pi's the limit },
journal = {Syracuse J. Gastronom.\ Math.}, year = {200BCE},volume = {10},pages={\textsc{CCCXV}--\textsc{CCCXIV}}}

@article{EulerE1776,Author = {Euler, Leonhard},Title = {All about E},
Journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},Year = {1776},Volume = {4},pages={1--2718}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{two.bib}
@book{BourbakiSets1970,Author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},Title={Th{\'e}orie des ensembles},
Year={1970},Publisher={Hermann},place={Paris}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{main.bib}
\addbibresource{two.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{refsegment} 

Archimedes~\cite{Archimedes200} and Euler~\cite{EulerE1776} studied the constants, $\pi$ and $e$,  respectively.

\end{refsegment}

\printbibliography[segment=1] % main

\defbibnote{readprenote}{Here are some suggested readings.}
\printbibliography[title={Additional Readings},prenote=readprenote,segment=2]

\begin{refsegment}

Bourbaki~\cite{BourbakiSets1970} treats set theory axiomatically.

\end{refsegment}

\end{document}
```

Notice that this works even though the citations to the 2nd bibliography appear after it is printed.

Comment: Wouldn't `multibib` be what you needed to hack? What else would you hope happen? (And I'm not saying it's easy -- especially for first-timers -- to build or mimic a citation/bibliography style for `biblatex`, but it is designed so that people can do this.)

Comment: But answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329431/how-use-amsplain-style-with-biblatex suggests that imitating `amsplain` bib style would be difficult.

Comment: The answer talks about how to customize, and says that it is ("arguably") easier to customize. I agree. Making a minor tweak to a `.bst` is not easier than creating a whole `.bbx`/`.cbx`, but I'm not sure that hacking `multibib`'s `\newcite`'s mechanism for `hyperref` support will be particularly easy. My guess is that it would be hard. There is the standard `biblatex` style `numeric`, which shouldn't be too hard to modify to match `amsplain` since the `numeric` style is a near analogue of BibTeX's `plain` style (I believe).

Comment: `biblatex` seems to be quite difficult to use, given that: I have two different `.bib` files, and my workflow, which is totally automated by TeXShop's `pdflatexmk` engine (and no direct command-line work). At least with `multibib` there was no processing issue there -- although of course the `hyperref` links were missing to the 2nd bibliography.

Comment: After examining `biblatex.pdf` I still don't understand how to create the two bibliographies such as shown in my sample document -- without modifying my preexisting `.bib` files (which for the real document, not the minimal sample I posted here) are lengthy.

Comment: There are several different ways to print multiple bibliographies using `biblatex`. It really depends on your use-case as to which method is best. Here's a simple one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35779/8528. I'm also fairly certain that TeXShop's "`pdflatexmk` engine" is just the `latexmk` script, which can be easily customized. But I've never used the program. Does this answer help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41970/8528?

Comment: Isn't that what the `defernumbers` option is for?

Comment: If I add option `defernumbers=true` when loading `biblatex`, then when the 2nd bibliography is about to be printed I get error: `<argument> ...xt@context }{\abx@field@localnumber 

l.34 ...{Additional Readings},prenote=readprenote]`

Comment: If I use your example file (using `biblatex` version 3.6), I do not get an error, and `[3]` is hyperlinked.

Comment: I *am* using `biblatex` version 3.6 and do get that error if in preamble I load the package with options `style=numeric,backend=bibtex,defernumbers=true` and in the body of document precede `\printbibliography` with `\newrefsection`. No error is I use `refsegment` environments, and option `segment=...` option in `\printbibliography` (and, as desired, numbering resumes for 2nd segment where it ended in 1st segment).